# append with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having issue, when jquery appending string instead of tags.
Here is my code:

```
$('.nested_comments_'+<%= @comment.parent.id %>).append("<div class='<%= 'nested_comments nested_comments_'+ @comment.id.to_s%>'></div>")
```

ANd this results in

```
"<div class='nested_comments nested_comments_584'></div>"
```

instead of html tag. WHat am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the last `)`;

Comment: I have it, just missed while copying

Answer (score 0):

<s>Are you sure you are not simply missing the last parentes:</s>

```
$('.nested_comments_'+<%= @comment.parent.id %>).append("<div class='<%= 'nested_comments nested_comments_'+ @comment.id.to_s%>'></div>");
```

You can use the reversed style, using [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
$("<div class='<%= 'nested_comments nested_comments_'+ @comment.id.to_s%>'></div>").appendTo('.nested_comments_'+<%= @comment.parent.id %>);
```

Comment: this returns me the same thing